# getting paid for work in Canada to a U.S bank account?

Tags: united-states, canada, banking

So I'll be *temporarily* transferred to one of our company's offices in Canada for about a year.

Can I be paid to my U.S bank account just so I won't have to transfer the money back to the U.S when I leave Canada?

If not, is there any bank that operates in both countries so I can just open one account and not have to worry about transferring money back?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your questions are probably best directed towards your payroll department, who have no doubt done this sort of thing before.  But I can answer about the cross-border banking question.

Of the "Big Five" Canadian banks, the one with the largest presence in the U.S. is almost certainly TD.  ("TD" stands for "Toronto Dominion", after all.)  TD Canada Trust, the Canadian version of the bank, seems to offer [a range of services for cross-border banking.](http://www.tdcanadatrust.com/products-services/banking/cross-border-banking/index.jsp)  I would recommend calling the *Canadian* bank and asking what they can do for you.  Trying to get things set up from the U.S. side is likely to lead to frustration;  Canadians needing to do financial stuff in the U.S. is much, much more common than Americans needing to do financial stuff in Canada, and the bank staff on each side of the border will probably be proportionately helpful.